# C# Beginner: Parent Callback method called instead of child's

Tags: c#

I have a little problem (still learning OOP). I'm calling parent's "GoTo" method and I want that object to be notified when it's done, but for some reason, callback method from parent class gets called instead of child's (even if I passed a child object as parameter).

**Question:** Clearly I'm missing something very basic, but I'm not sure what. What do I need to do so that the child's "Imthere" method will be called instead of parents? (Casting to the specific Child object in parent's method is not applicable since I want to reuse the same code snipped over different child objects).

```
public class Parent {

    public void GoTo(Parent movingObject) { 

        //Random code here.

        OnComplete(movingObject.Imthere);

    }

    protected void Imthere() { 

        //This gets called when some task is Completed!

        Log("Parent");
    }
}


public class Child : Parent
{



    protected void Imthere()
    {

        //This SHOULD get's called when task is completed, but it's not.

        Log("Child");
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: I believe you need to make `Imthere` virtual in `Parent` and `override` it in `Child`.

Comment: You got a warning when you compiled this code saying that it was probably wrong. Attention new programmer: **we added those warnings for a reason. Pay attention to them.** They are there to help you discover these problems and fix them. Can you describe why it is that you ignored the warning? Was it unclear, or hard to see, or what?

Comment: Hey. I didn’t get any compile warnings because Unity didn’t show them. I’m coding in VS but everything is compiled by the game  engine.

Comment: @rootpanthera: Figure out how to get access to those warnings as soon as possible.  I'm sure there's a way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It needs to be a virtual method in the parent:

```
public class Parent {

    //... snip

    protected virtual void Imthere() { 
        Log("Parent");
    }
}
```

And the child needs to add the `override` keyword to its own version of the method:

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    protected override void Imthere()
    {
        Log("Child");
    }
}
```